# How can i able to send the failed code snippet in codepipeline via email?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-codepipeline

**Usecase**

I have `codepipeline` for which i had enabled the `cloudwatch events` which trigger when there is a stage change in my codepipline. But i want to see the error logs maybe not all, atleast a `snippet` of what went wrong if there is a failure in codebuild or any stage.

Is it possible to get that in codepipeline because i didnt find any thing related to this scenario in any documentations ?

Any help is appreciated
Thanks